# MapView snippet objective c dot notation vs message passing notation?

Tags: objective-c

I saw quite a few examples with maps around the net with

```
MapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
```

What would be the corresponding equivalent with message passing notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the property declaration. In the standard case when no custom setter is declared it is:

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
```

Note that you probably want `YES` instead of `TRUE`.

Comment: I was using "mapview showsUserLocation: TRUE;" This was giving me a red error NO visible @interface for 'MKMapView' declares selector by that name... apparently the method name is not the same as the property name.

Comment: I find myself coming back to your response over and over again. The deeper I go into Objective-C the more i appreciate message passing notation over dot notation.